# ZF2 wants truncated controller name when rendering template, why?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am creating a ZF2 module called `Template`. See below:

[image]

In my `module.config.php`, I have my view manager and controllers configured as following:

```
return array(
// Telling where the views are
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'template/my/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/template/myctrl/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
// Mapping controller names to controller files
'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Template\Controller\MyCtrl' => 'Template\Controller\MyController'
     )
 ),
```

In `template_map`, I have to use the `template/my/index` value instead of `template/myctrl/index`, otherwise, I get the following error message:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render:
    Unable to render template "template/my/index";
    resolver could not resolve to a file
```

Why?

Comment: Comment config `template_path_stack`

Comment: Is the `template_map` in your question the one that works, or the one that doesn't? I'm a little unclear in what situation you get that error.

Comment: It's the one that works

Comment: It looks like a bug to me

Comment: Just filed it: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7616

Comment: Controller class is used to resolve template, not the controller manager key or alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a little confusing as you're having trouble rendering view templates in a module called 'template', however, I don't think it's a bug.

Assuming you don't try and render a specific view from the controller, ZF will determine the view to use based on the module name, controller name, and action name. (I don't think the alias you use in the controller `invokables` is relevant.) In the case of the controller, it will remove any namespaces and strip off the 'Controller' suffix, if present. So `template/my/index` is what you're left with.

You don't *have* to use the template_map (it's optional and there to improve performance), but in your case, because your view folder is named `myctrl`, the rendering only works if you use the template map to map what ZF is looking for to the actual location.

I'd suggest you just rename your `myctrl` view folder to `my` and remove the template map entry (for now), and then everything should work as normal.

Comment: I have made some tests and indeed the alias I use in the controller's invokables is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JVestry said this seems like a bug. So, let's try something else first.

Locate your `templatemap_generator.php` file. It should e in your `ZF2/bin` folder. Navigate to your module folder e.g. `Application` directory where the `src, view, config` folders are. Open a terminal and type `php ../../vendor/ZF2/bin/templatemap_generator.php` ZF will create a template map in your module directory. Now to use this template, simply modify your module.config.php file

```
return array(
// Telling where the views are
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => include __DIR__ . '/../template_map.php',
),
// Mapping controller names to controller files
'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Template\Controller\MyCtrl' => 'Template\Controller\MyController'
     )
 ),
```

In your `myAction()`

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate("template/myctrl/index");
```

I call `template/my/index` because this is what the generator is going to produce, but you are free to rename to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `controller_map` to more fine control over the name of a rendering template.

So in your case you may do:

```
return array(
// Telling where the views are
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'template/my/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/template/myctrl/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'controller_map' => array(
        'Template\Controller\MyCtrl' => 'template/myctrl',
    ),
),
// Mapping controller names to controller files
'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Template\Controller\MyCtrl' => 'Template\Controller\MyController'
     )
),
```

See: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5670